# ¿Cómo saber cuantos elementos se repiten en un determinado contenedor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero conocer el número de elementos que se repiten adentro de un contenedor para después darle cierto propiedad. He visto que con `$(".item").length` ya se obtiene un valor pero yo tengo en otro `` también otros elementos con la misma clase y estoy pensando poner lo siguiente en js:

```
var cont1 = $('.carrusel1');
var res1 = cont1.$('.item').length;
```

```
<div id="carrusel1">
    <div class="MS-content">
    <?php
        while($destaca = mysqli_fetch_array($queryD)) {
        ?>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img-trj-prod" src="<?php echo $destaca['path_foto'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $destaca['descripcion_producto'] ?>" >
            <div class="nombre_producto">
                <h2><?php echo $destaca['descripcion_producto'] ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="info-trj">
            <div class="precio-trj">
                <i class="icon-dollar"></i>
                <label><?php echo $destaca['precio'] ?></label>
            </div>
            <a data-cod="<?php echo $destaca['id_producto'] ?>"><i class="agrega-carro icon-cart-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="caracteristicas">
            <ul id="<?php echo $destaca['descripcion_producto'] ?>"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Tengo otro `<div id="carrusel2>` con la misma estructura que el carrusel1 pero obviamente cambia el nombre de la variable que contiene el mysqli_fetch_array" de una consulta realizada.

Luego de haber intentado lo del javascript y poner un `console.log(res1)` para ver el resultado no me funcionó, desconozco las razones y estoy investigando sobre el respectivo tema y también sobre el cómo contar los elementos de un contenedor

Comment: Incluye el código relevante donde tienes el problema, me refiero al HTML para ver qué elementos tienes con todo y sus clases y ver la manera de contarlos.

Comment: Listo, ya edite la pregunta y agregué la parte del html

Comment: Los selectores de jQuery son tus amigos: `$('.carrusel1 .item').length` encuentra todos los elementos con clase `item` que estén dentro de un elemento con clase `carrusel1`

Comment: y si en caso de que el contendor no tenga una clase sino un id solo se cambia el ``$('.carrusel1')`` por ``$('#carrusel1')``?